# How to combine one letter and dot into a single row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with two columns. The columns is Word and Tag. The df looks as follows:

```
                     Word   Tag
0                  bentuk    A
1                   fisik    B 
2              masyarakat    C 
3                   serta    D  
4              kebudayaan    E
5                    yang    F
6              dihasilkan    G
7                       .    H
8                       ;    I
9                 William    O
10                      A    O
11                      .    B
12                Haviland   X
```

and I'd like to merge some row contains one letter with dot `.` `letter+.` to one row. If there's a word meet dot, it won't merge. So the output should be the following:

```
0                  bentuk    A
1                   fisik    B 
2              masyarakat    C 
3                   serta    D  
4              kebudayaan    E
5                    yang    F
6              dihasilkan    G
7                       .    H
8                       ;    I
9                 William    O
10                     A.    O
11                Haviland   X
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Note: I have tried solution from @jezrael, but the output is

```
0                  bentuk    A
1                   fisik    B 
2              masyarakat    C 
3                   serta    D
4                      A.    O
5              kebudayaan    E
6                    yang    F
7              dihasilkan    G
8                       .    H
9                       ;    I
10                 William    O
11                Haviland   X
```

the results are out of order

Answer (score 1):

I modify previous solution with match letters `A-Z` and `a-z` with `.` after it:

```
m1 = df['Word'].str.contains("^[A-Za-z]{1}$") & df['Word'].shift(-1).eq('.')
m2 = df['Word'].eq('.') & df['Word'].shift().str.contains("^[A-Za-z]{1}$")

m = m1 | m2
g = (~m).cumsum().where(m)

m5 = g.map(g.value_counts()) == 2
g1 = g.where(m5, np.arange(len(df)) + .5)

df1 = (df.groupby(g1, as_index=False)
          .agg({'Word': ''.join, 'Tag' :'first'}))
print(df1)
          Word Tag
0       bentuk   A
1        fisik   B
2   masyarakat   C
3        serta   D
4   kebudayaan   E
5         yang   F
6   dihasilkan   G
7            .   H
8            ;   I
9      William   O
10          A.   O
11    Haviland   X
```

EDIT: After looking for problem there are cumulative values shifted, pandas `groupby` by default sorting, so changed order. Solution is add `sort=False` parameter to `groupby`:

```
df1 = (df.dropna()
        .groupby(g1, as_index=False, sort=False)
        .agg({'Word': ''.join, 'Tag' :'first'}))
print(df1.loc[4750:4770])
             Word       Tag
4750       dengan         O
4751  mempelajari         O
4752        aneka         O
4753        warna         O
4754            ,         O
4755       bentuk         O
4756        fisik         O
4757   masyarakat         O
4758        serta         O
4759   kebudayaan         O
4760         yang         O
4761   dihasilkan         O
4762            .         O
4763            ;         O
4764      William  B-PERSON
4765           A.  I-PERSON
4766     Haviland  I-PERSON
4767            :         O
4768  Antropologi         O
4769       adalah         O
4770        studi         O
```

Comment: can you explain ```^[A-Za-z]{1}$```?

Comment: @winnie - Sure - `^` is for start of string, `[A-Za-z]` is for match lettters `ABCD...Zabcd...z`, `{1}` is for only 1 value  and `$` is for end of string

Comment: aah I see, anyway the code from you makes the result out of order, as I explained more at question

Comment: @winnie - Are data confidental?

Comment: @winnie - Yes, if check my profile and run code get my email.

Comment: I've sent u email, have u received it?